# Run a list of classes in parallel which implement the same interface in java

Tags: java, class, generics, radix, completable-future

I have created the below mentioned base and derived class

```
public abstract class ContextBase {
    private String customerID;
    private String marketplaceID;
}

public class ReturnContext extends ContextBase {
    private String returnID;
}
```

Then I created an interface which has a method called perform and some classes which implements this interface

```
public interface ValidatorInterface<T extends ContextBase> {

    CompletableFuture<List<String>> perform(T context);
}

public class AlphaValidator implements ValidatorInterface<ContextBase> {
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<List<String>> perform(ContextBase contextBase) {
        ....
    }
}

public class BetaValidator implements ValidatorInterface<ReturnContext> {
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<List<String>> perform(ReturnContext context) {
        ....
    }
}
```

I want to run a list of classes which implements the ValidatorInterface in parallel, So I created a ValidatorRunner class

```
public class ValidatorRunner<T extends ContextBase> {

    public List<String> runValidators(final T context,
                                       final List<ValidatorInterface<T>> validatorsList) {

        final Map<String, CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futureAggregatedProblems = new LinkedHashMap<>(validatorsList.size());
        List<String> problems = new ArrayList<>();
        validatorsList.forEach(validator -> runValidator(
                validator, futureAggregatedProblems, context));

        futureAggregatedProblems.forEach((validatorName, futureProblems) -> {
            try {
                problems.addAll(futureProblems.get(FUTURE_TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | CompletionException | TimeoutException ex) {
                // TODO Do not ignore InterruptedException
                throw new InternalServiceException("Error executing validators : " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        });

        return problems;
    }

    private void runValidator(final ValidatorInterface<T> validator,
                              final Map<String, CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futureAggregatedProblems,
                              final T context) {

        futureAggregatedProblems.put(validator.getClass().getCanonicalName(), validator.perform(context));
    }
```

This implementation does seem to work when I do this

```
ValidatorRunner<ReturnContext> validatorRunner = new ValidatorRunner<ReturnContext>();
ReturnContext context = new ReturnContext();
BetaValidator beta = new BetaValidator();
List<ValidatorInterface<ReturnContext>> validatorList = new ArrayList<>();
validatorList.add(beta);
List<String> problems = validatorRunner.runValidators(context, validatorList);
```

The problem is that AlphaValidator is implemented on base type (ContextBase) while BetaValidator is implemented on derived type (ReturnContext). I want to run AlphaValidator and BetaValidator in parallel while passing an instance of ReturnContext as context. How it can be achieved ?

**EDIT 1**

The reason I created ValidatorInterface as **T extends ContextBase** because I want each validator to use either a ContextBase or a derived class of ContextBase.

I have created AlphaValidator on base type ContextBase because I want the AlphaValidator to be created and executed using any of the derived class of ContextBase. While BetaValidator is created on ReturnContext because I want the BetaValidator to be created and executed using ReturnContext only.
Lets suppose I create a new derived class called ReplacementContext which extends ContextBase and also a new validator called as GammaValidator on derived type ReplacementContext. I want to be able to run AlphaValidator and GammaValidator using ReplacementContext. AlphaValidator and BetaValidator should run on ReturnContext. But I dont want to run BetaValidator and GammaValidator in parallel because they serve different purpose and separate contexts (thats why they are created on separate contexts, ReturnContext and ReplacementContext respectively).

Comment: It looks like `ValidatorInterface` should not be generic; each validator should accept any `ContextBase`. Otherwise, why would you pass the "wrong" context to collection of validations when some of them don't work with that context?

Comment: @erickson I have made an edit on the question to reflect on what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem with the above code

When providing a single concrete context for multiple validators each validator **MUST** support the given context class. This is a design issue.

#### My solution

An alternative solution is to provide multiple contexts to the `runValidate` method where each context can placed next to the correct validators.

Given my example the `ContextProcessor.of()` will take care that the compiler only allows correct assignments for validators and contexts.

I suggest to change your `ValidatorRunner` to a similar version to this code:

```java
public class ValidatorRunner {

    static class ContextProcessor<T extends ContextBase> {
        private final List<ValidatorInterface<T>> validators;
        private final T context;

        private ContextProcessor(List<ValidatorInterface<T>> validators, T context) {
            this.validators = validators;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public static <V extends ValidatorInterface<C>, C extends ContextBase> ContextProcessor<C> of(List<V> validators, C context) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return new ContextProcessor<>((List<ValidatorInterface<C>>) validators, context);
        }

        public List<ValidatorInterface<T>> getValidators() {
            return validators;
        }

        public T getContext() {
            return context;
        }
    }

    public List<String> runValidators(final List<ContextProcessor<? extends ContextBase>> processors) {

        var validators = processors.stream().map(p -> p.validators.size()).reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0);
        var latch = new CountDownLatch(validators);

        var problemStack = new ArrayList<String>();

        //noinspection unchecked
        processors.forEach(p -> p.getValidators().forEach(validator ->
                runValidator((ValidatorInterface<ContextBase>) validator, p.getContext())
                        .orTimeout(10_000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .thenAccept(problems -> {
                            problemStack.addAll(problems);
                            latch.countDown();
                        })
        ));

        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return problemStack;
    }

    private CompletableFuture<List<String>> runValidator(final ValidatorInterface<ContextBase> validator, final ContextBase context) {
        return validator.perform(context);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var problems = new ValidatorRunner().runValidators(
                List.of(
                        ContextProcessor.of(List.of(new AlphaValidator(), new AlphaValidator()), new ReplacementContext()),
                        ContextProcessor.of(List.of(new AlphaValidator()), new ContextBase() {}),
                        ContextProcessor.of(List.of(new BetaValidator(), new BetaValidator()), new ReturnContext())
                )
        );

        System.out.println(problems);
    }
}
```

When running the provided `main` method, the following result is expected:

```
[error within context ReplacementContext, error within context ReplacementContext, error within context , error within context ReturnContext, error within context ReturnContext]
```

Where every validator has returned the `Future` String `"error within context" + context.getClass().getSimpleName()`

Maybe this will help you find a way to solve your problem.

Comment: When AlphaValidator runs, it should be using ReturnContext as ReturnContext is derived from ContextBase. Am I making a fundamental mistake somewhere ? I dont want the Alpha Validator to run on ContextBase but on the derived class of ContextBase. I created Alpha Validator on ContextBase because lets suppose ReplacementContext extends ContextBase, then AlphaValidator should run on ReplacementContext as well. Its a common validator for all the derived classes of ContextBase

Comment: I understand your problem. The context supplier can do exactly what you want (providing a ReplacementContext). I guess that the core strategy may be wrong. The problem can be tracked down to the fact that a concrete validator class needs a context or derived one. With this in mind a validate method on the `ValidatorInterface` may be a better option. Ill try to make an example that provides a single entrypoint

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have also added the edit section to the question where I provided some more clarification.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Maybe this will give you a clearer overview for the problem :)